How do you vectorize a function that assigns a value to an element based on a look up to a reference table?
I'm trying to match a category to each string in a vector based on it's adjacent value on a reference data.frame. Essentially this is the same thing as vlookup in Excel.
Here is an example of the vector I'm assigning values to:
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "F")
Here is an example of the data.frame called class_ref_table I am referencing:



code
phase
desc




A
phase1
Desc 1


B
phase2
Desc 2


C
phase3
Desc 3


D
phase4
Desc 4


E
phase5
Desc 5


F
phase6
Desc 6



class_ref_table <- structure(list(code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), phase = c("phase1", 
"phase2", "phase3", "phase4", "phase5", "phase6"), desc = c("Desc 1", 
"Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4", "Desc 5", "Desc 6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))

Here is my current code:
class_reference <- function(vector, column) {
  temp_vector <- seq_along(vector)
  for (word in class_ref_table[[1]]) {
    z <- which(class_ref_table[[1]] == word)
    temp_vector[grep(word, vector)] <- class_ref_table[z, column]
  }
  temp_vector
}

Result example:
class_reference(x, 2)

[1] "phase1"
[2] "phase2"
[3] "phase3"
[4] "phase1"
[5] "phase4"
[6] "phase6"


Currently this code works fine, but it's a little slow. Currently it takes ~8.5 minutes to run this across ~3000 vectors with a total of ~100,000 elements. Is there a way to vectorize this function so it's really fast?
I vectorized a similar function before which reduced the run time from exponential time to linear time (10 minutes for 400,000 elements down to 0.2 seconds), however I have no idea how to do something similar here.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

You could try indexing using match:
class_ref_table[match(x, class_ref_table$code), "phase"]

Output
# [1] "phase1" "phase2" "phase3" "phase1" "phase4" "phase6"

(If you want to return the whole data frame, just remove the “phase” from the above code)
This seems to be about 12x faster than the original function:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  op_function = class_reference(vector = x, 2),
  match = class_ref_table[match(x, class_ref_table$code), "phase"]
)

#        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
# op_function 180.030 190.2205 202.04175 197.2335 199.0600 562.735   100  a 
# match        14.746  15.5965  17.16169  16.4825  17.8845  54.653   100   b

This seems to hold true if you increase the size of the data frame (here, 1000x the size of the example data)
big_df <- data.frame(sapply(df, rep.int, times = 1e3))

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr        min           lq         mean      median          uq         max neval cld
# op_function 951551.544 1038882.8955 1196466.9788 1201759.472 1314753.790 1638215.506   100  a 
# match          146.573     166.3865     189.6446     183.148     211.942     250.211   100   b


You could also convert your vector x into a dataframe and use an inner_join.  This outputs a dataframe with more information:
library(dplyr)

x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "F")

df_x <- data.frame(code = x)

class_ref_table <- structure(list(code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), phase = c("phase1", 
"phase2", "phase3", "phase4", "phase5", "phase6"), desc = c("Desc 1", 
"Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4", "Desc 5", "Desc 6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))

inner_join(df_x, class_ref_table)
  code  phase   desc
1    A phase1 Desc 1
2    B phase2 Desc 2
3    C phase3 Desc 3
4    A phase1 Desc 1
5    D phase4 Desc 4
6    F phase6 Desc 6


CReate a named vector and lookup the names:
with(class_ref_table, setNames(phase, code))[x]
##        A        B        C        A        D        F 
## "phase1" "phase2" "phase3" "phase1" "phase4" "phase6" 

Based on the median column it is 16x faster in this test using the data in the question (and Note below):
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(unit = "relative",
  class_reference = class_reference(x, 2), 
  setNames = with(class_ref_table, setNames(phase, code))[x]
)
## Unit: relative
##             expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
##  class_reference 21.45902 18.84083 18.45559 16.0528 13.98784 129.3793   100  a 
##         setNames  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.0000  1.00000   1.0000   100   b

Note
Input in reproducible form:
class_ref_table <- data.frame(
  code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  phase = c("phase1", "phase2", "phase3", "phase4", "phase5", "phase6"),
  desc = c("Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4", "Desc 5", "Desc 6")
)

x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "F")

class_reference <- function(vector, column) {
  temp_vector <- seq_along(vector)
  for (word in class_ref_table[[1]]) {
    z <- which(class_ref_table[[1]] == word)
    temp_vector[grep(word, vector)] <- class_ref_table[z, column]
  }
  temp_vector
}

